# The moment store files in SDCard is very slow(taking more time)

Tags: android, sd-card, file-storage

The moment store files in SDCard, it's taking a long time but if I store files in internal storage its taking less time.

My code:

```
public File getTileViewImageDirectory() {
    // check SDCard if available or not, if available store in SDCard    
    // else store in internal storage
    if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && !android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        File[] dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
        File directory = new File(dirs[dirs.length > 1 ? 1 : 0].getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + AppConstants.TILEVIEW_IMAGE_LOCATION);
        return directory;
    } else {
        return new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + AppConstants.TILEVIEW_IMAGE_LOCATION);
    }
}
```

Note: If SDCard not available than default it will store in internal storage.

When using the internal storage it be fast (under 30 sec), but in external storage it is taking longer time (over 1 min).

How can I decrease the time when using external storage?

Answer (score 0):

To save directly to the SD card will be always slower. The only way to improve the speed is to use/buy a [high speed SD card](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/).

Also looking at your code I should warn you that starting in Android 4.4 and above the SD card is no longer accessible with the common File API. You will need to use instead the new [Storage Access Frameork](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Also take into account that in Android Q and above, SAF has been enforced to be the only way to access the SD card, so there are no workarounds or hacks for such versions.

Comment: Will this Storage Access Framework will support store data in sdcard

Comment: The SAF (Storage Access Framework) is the new official way to work with the SD card in Android KitKat and above.

Comment: SAF is VERY VERY SLOW

Comment: @FindOutIslanNow: SAF is slow, but your complain should go to Google, they are forcing developers to use it. No matter how much you dislike SAF, this is what Google forces you to use.